# Configure postgresql from CUBIC chroot

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, postgresql, chroot

I'm customizing a Lubuntu 22.04 image to have a ready-to-use environment after installation. One of the points - I need to have postgresql installed and configured, means that a database is created and a certain user granted with permissions. When I run `psql` from chroot, it fails.

I've seen few similar questions - configure RabbitMQ, enable systemd service from chroot, but none of them has been answered. Is it something nobody knows about, or did I try to do it the wrong way?

Comment: It reads like you have an answer and have included it at the bottom of the question. This is not the way to do this. At the bottom of the question is an Answer Your Own Question option. Use this and put the answer in there.

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is:

```
service postgresql start
```

to start service

To see the status of all services `service --status-all` command can be called.